# How to change text color of webview in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, html, css, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I need to take the html string from the service and print it to the screen and I wrote a code like this

```
    val htmlString = state.response?.data?.content ?: ""               
    val color = Color.Transparent

            AndroidView(
                     factory = { context ->
                         WebView(context).apply {
                             loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8")
                             setBackgroundColor(color.toArgb())
                         }
                     }
           )
```

---

I want to make the text color this

```
val Colors.defaultThemeColor: Color
    get() = if (isLight) Color.Black else Color.White
```

I read that I need to add css to change the text color and I did something like

```
val htmlContent = """
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                color: #${String.format("%06X", 0xFFFFFF and textColor)}; 
              
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        $htmlString
    </body>
    </html>
""".trimIndent()
                         
                    
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
               WebView(context).apply {
                   loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8")
                    setBackgroundColor(color.toArgb())
                }
        }
    )
```

but this time nothing appears on the screen

here is part of html string from service

> "<script async type="text/javascript"
> src=\xxx"><div
> class="icerik"><p dir="ltr"><span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxxx.
>
> \r\n\r\n<h2
> dir="ltr">**<span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxx**\r\n\r\n<p dir="ltr"><span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxxx
> tüketimi; M\r\n\r\n<p dir="ltr"><span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxx \r\n\r\n<h2
> dir="ltr">**<span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxx**\r\n\r\n<p
> dir="ltr"><span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxx\r\n\r\n<h2 dir="ltr">**<span
> id="docs-internal-guid-8c062cca-7fff-9f91-8ec8-75afafa8333b">xxx**
> .... .."

How to change text color of webview's content in android compose kotlin ? How can I do that

**SOLVED**:

I solved the problem that I added dynamic color like below and it worked.

```
 val txtColor = if (!isSystemInDarkTheme()) "black" else "white"
                              
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body {
                    color: $txtColor; 
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
           $htmlString
        </body>
    </html>
"""
                            AndroidView(
                                factory = { context ->
                                    WebView(context).apply {
                                        loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8")
                                        setBackgroundColor(color.toArgb())
                                    }
                                }
                            )
```